# Simple python server "connection refused" error

Tags: python, linux, tcp, firewall, iptables

I found code for a very simple python server and client. When i first ran it I ran the server and client on the same machine in different terminals and it worked fine. However now I am running the server on my raspberry pi and running my client on my desktop and I am getting a "connection refused error. My instincts tell me that It is the firewall blocking the port I am using but I used the following command I found to open the port.

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 4042 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Both my client and server are connecting to this port # in my python code.
When I run `sudo nmap -sS -O 127.0.0.1` on my pi I get the following output:

```
Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-08-29 23:52 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00027s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see http://nmap.org/submit/ ).
TCP/IP fingerprint:
OS:SCAN(V=6.00%E=4%D=8/29%OT=22%CT=1%CU=37241%PV=N%DS=0%DC=L%G=Y%TM=521FDEE
OS:0%P=armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi)SEQ(SP=103%GCD=1%ISR=105%TI=Z%CI=Z%II=I
OS:%TS=7)OPS(O1=M400CST11NW3%O2=M400CST11NW3%O3=M400CNNT11NW3%O4=M400CST11N
OS:W3%O5=M400CST11NW3%O6=M400CST11)WIN(W1=8000%W2=8000%W3=8000%W4=8000%W5=8
OS:000%W6=8000)ECN(R=Y%DF=Y%T=41%W=8018%O=M400CNNSNW3%CC=Y%Q=)T1(R=Y%DF=Y%T
OS:=41%S=O%A=S+%F=AS%RD=0%Q=)T2(R=N)T3(R=N)T4(R=Y%DF=Y%T=41%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R
OS:%O=%RD=0%Q=)T5(R=Y%DF=Y%T=41%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)T6(R=Y%DF=Y%T=
OS:41%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)T7(R=Y%DF=Y%T=41%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0
OS:%Q=)U1(R=Y%DF=N%T=41%IPL=164%UN=0%RIPL=G%RID=G%RIPCK=G%RUCK=G%RUD=G)IE(R
OS:=Y%DFI=N%T=41%CD=S)

Network Distance: 0 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 29.35 seconds
```

and when I run `iptables -L` i get:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:4042 state ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Which address and port is your server bound to? Can you run the `nmap` command on your pi server with `-p 4042` to scan that port specifically? It doesn't seem to be showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to revisit this to say that while it was not a problem with the ip tables on my raspberry pi, my connection was being blocked by a firewall on the computer I was using as the client of the server.

To anyone else attempting this experiment, I advise you to add exceptions for the client and host in each others firewalls to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try "service iptables stop". This will disable iptables and if you see the connection request go through, then you know that iptables is the culprit.

Comment: hmm when i run that command it gives me "iptables: unrecognized service"

Comment: The above command works for Fedora/RedHat. What OS are you running?

Comment: oh sorry its debian, specifically the raspberry pi default os (raspbian i believe its called)

Comment: Oh.. that makes sense. Can you please try this: "sudo ufw disable". Here is the reference: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-server-disable-firewall/

Comment: I would try disabling it with GUI option, that should work too: System > Administration > Firewall configuration option.

Comment: the connection was still refused, and there is no gui option if i enable my desktop interface

Comment: Can you use tcpdump to see if packets are making to the server box and back? Also, we probably need to disable firewall on both devices since it is possible that the outgoing TCP SYN might be making it through but the incoming TCP SYN-ACK might be getting dropped.

Comment: okay, I tried disabling ufw on my machine running the client and it was still refused, i should add that i can successfully ssh into my server machine from the machine running the client

Comment: Can you try to do telnet on that port? For example "telnet IP_SERVER PORT_NUMBER"

Comment: If the server is not sitting on that port, then the telnet should fail with connection refused error.

Comment: Sorry for not responding, the telnet test failed as you predicted, however i cannot figure out how to open the port to connections

Comment: I would recommend asking a new question on Raspberry PI site and keeping it specific to opening a port in Raspberry PI: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/?as=1 . You can mention as an FYI that you are trying open the port for socket. But that hsould not be the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "-m state --state ESTABLISHED" from the rule. This will not match your SYN packet and will get rejected.

You use "-m state --state ESTABLISHED" to skip rule checking for established connections.